# How do I get the text between two characters of a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
var people = [
    '<option value=\'64\'>Tom',
    '<option value=\'76\'>Dan',
];
```

I am looping through each item in the array to extract the value (like the number 64 in the first item) and the text (like Tom in the first item). I tried multiple ways of extracting these details from each item but I am unable to. I even tried using substrings and other methods. Can someone tell me how to extract this information?

Comment: did you try regular expressions?

Comment: I'm not really good with Regular Expressions. I tried a few from some Googling I did but they didn't help. Do you know what the Regular Expression for this should look like?

Comment: I notice that this text looks like the HTML for the contents of a `<select>` element. Is there a menu in the DOM with these values already? You may be able to get the values more easily from the DOM instead of the raw text.

Comment: @TheSpooniest I'm not operating inside of a browser. I'm actually parsing some stuff on Node.js. I can't directly access the DOM like I would in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple split :

```js
var str = '<option value=\'64\'>Tom';

var tmpStr = str.split("'");

var number = (tmpStr[1].split("\\"))[0];

var name = (tmpStr[2].split(">"))[1];

document.write(number + " " + name);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use a regular expression in such a case.

For example:

```
var things = people.map(function(s){
  return s.match(/(\d+)\W+(\w+)$/).slice(1)
});
```

This builds this array:

```
[ ["64", "Tom"], ["76", "Dan"] ]
```

You might want to adapt it for your precise needs:

- check an array is returned by `match`, if some strings might be invalid
- change the regex if the pattern is more variable

Note that you probably shouldn't have such an array to start with. If you generate it server-side, you should opt for the generation of a JSON structure instead and let the client script build the interface from the data, instead of building it from something which is neither clean data nor GUI.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I am not allowed to edit the server response in this project. I'm playing with what I have.